# android Messagebox

Tags: android

android Messagebox doesn't show because of **finish** call, how to make this function wait for ok and then close

```
public void msbox(String str,String str2)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                      
    dlgAlert.setMessage(str2);
    dlgAlert.setTitle(str);              
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
    finish(); 
}
```

should be like this

```
public void msbox(String str,String str2)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                      
    dlgAlert.setTitle(str); 
    dlgAlert.setMessage(str2); 
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             finish(); 
        }
   });
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782676/alertdialog-doesnt-wait-for-input

Comment: should I provide it as an aswer if you used it like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see SO question: [AlertDialog doesn't wait for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782676/alertdialog-doesnt-wait-for-input)

you will have to implement callback (OnClickListener) when user clicks OK on AlertDialog.

This all because Android dialog boxes are not modal (non-blocking invoker thread)

```
dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // call your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a dialog box(Message Box,named in c#,vb.net etc) in android programming then just copy this code and paste it in the click event of any button where you need it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
    .setTitle("Deleting a Contact No")
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {       
               //do some thing here which you need
    }
    });             
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {   
        dialog.dismiss();           
        }
    });         
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```